# Searching in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array, say A sorted with respect to Column 0. e.g.

| Col.0 | Col.1 | Col.2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2.45 | 3.25 |
| 11 | 2.95 | 4 |
| 12 | 3.45 | 4.25 |
| 15 | 3.95 | 5 |
| 18 | 4.45 | 5.25 |
| 21 | 4.95 | 6 |
| 23 | 5.45 | 6.25 |
| 27 | 5.95 | 7 |
| 29 | 6.45 | 7.25 |
| 32 | 6.95 | 8 |
| 35 | 7.45 | 8.25 |

The entries in each row is unique i.e. Col. 0 is the identification number of a co-ordinate in xy plane, Columns 1 and 2 are x and y co-ordinates of these points.
I have another array B (rows can contain duplicate data). Column 0 and Column 1 store x and y co-ordinates.

| Col.0 | Col.1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2.45 | 3.25 |
| 4.45 | 5.25 |
| 6.45 | 7.25 |
| 2.45 | 3.25 |

My aim is to find the row index number in array A corresponding to data in array B without using for loop. So, in this case, my output should be `[0,4,8,0]`.
Now, I know that with numpy searchsorted lookup for multiple data can be done in one shot. But, it can be used to compare with a single column of A and not multiple columns. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `searchsorted` won't help because the array is not sorted by the column(s) you're actually searching in.

Comment: Please avoid posting tables for data frames. Posting the actual data (or even better the code for data frame) would help us run your example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pure numpy solution:

My intuition is that I take the difference `c` between `a[:,1:]` and `b` by broadcasting, such that `c` is of shape `(11, 4, 2)`. The rows that match will be all zeros. Then I do `c == False` to obtain a mask. I do `c.all(2)` which results in a boolean array of shape `(11, 4)`, where all `True` elements represents matches between `a` and `b`. Then I simply use `np.nonzero` to obtain the indices of said elements.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [10, 2.45, 3.25],
    [11, 2.95, 4],
    [12, 3.45, 4.25],
    [15, 3.95, 5],
    [18, 4.45, 5.25],
    [21, 4.95, 6],
    [23, 5.45, 6.25],
    [27, 5.95, 7],
    [29, 6.45, 7.25],
    [32, 6.95, 8],
    [35, 7.45, 8.25],
])

b = np.array([
    [2.45, 3.25],
    [4.45, 5.25],
    [6.45, 7.25],
    [2.45, 3.25],
])

c = (a[:,np.newaxis,1:]-b) == False
rows, cols = c.all(2).nonzero()
print(rows[cols.argsort()])
# [0 4 8 0]
```

Comment: This really helped. I will now be able to implement this logic in a very large array.

Comment: @SudiptaLalBasu Nice to see that it worked for you! However, I noticed that my code matches when either the first or second element are equal. It may have worked for you anyways if you had all continuous points, as they are unlikely to get exact same values, but it is not strictly correct as it can match too mutch. To ensure that you require both elements to match, change:  `rows, cols = c.sum(2).nonzero()` to `rows, cols = c.all(2).nonzero()`, I will edit my submission to reflect this. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge in pandas:

```
df2.merge(df1.reset_index(),how='left',left_on=['Col.0','Col.1'],right_on=['Col.1','Col.2'])['index']
```

output:

```
0    0
1    4
2    8
3    0
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

and if you like it as array:

```
df2.merge(df1.reset_index(),how='left',left_on=['Col.0','Col.1'],right_on=['Col.1','Col.2'])['index'].to_numpy()
#array([0, 4, 8, 0])
```